# How do I reverse an animation when a button is pressed?

Tags: ios, core-animation

How do I create a method that reverses an animation if I call it? In my project I have a UIViewController and a sub view of this controller that does all the background animation. What the animation does is not very important. It just lets some rectangles appear when the app is opened:

```
-(void)rectBottomAnimation
{    
    NSLog(@"ANIMATION START");    

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    for (int xcord = 0; xcord <= screenWidth; xcord += 6) {
        //BOTTOM
        [self newRectWithX:xcord y:screenHeight height:0];

        CABasicAnimation* fromBottomAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"bounds"];
        fromBottomAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect: _rectangle];
        fromBottomAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(xcord, 0, 7, -(screenHeight)/1.4)];
        fromBottomAnimation.duration = 0.3;
        fromBottomAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        fromBottomAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        [_myLayer addAnimation: fromBottomAnimation forKey: @"resize"];
    } 
}
```

So the question is: what would a method look like, that reverses this animation when a button gets pressed?

Comment: `removedOnCompletion = NO;` 

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Sorry for my bad grammar im from Germany :D  what is wrong about removedOnCompletion = NO ?

Comment: When you don't update the model value (the actual property) and don't remove the animation you have the same data in two places (the property and how the view appears on screen) and they are out of sync. This easily get's you into weird bugs: for example not being able to tap buttons because hit testing uses the property value but the button appears somewhere else on the screen, or maybe you check the model's position and it's not what you expect it to be, etc.

Comment: ill work on that (: thanks

Comment: do you know an answer to my first question?